# Which Flash Video Player can give exact position (timestamp / frame index) information

Tags: flash, video-streaming, jwplayer

I'm looking for a Flash Video Player (something like JWPlayer) that I can embed in an html page, that provides a JavaScript API with a method to get the exact timestamp (aka position, or frame-count) for the current frame.

Is this something that Flash supports?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

[flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) has very good javascript Api. You can do anything with it.
You can obtain time using getTime() function. [Docs here](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/player.html)